# Change NSURL selected from UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview, feed, nsurl

In my app I load "feed link" into a tableView. It works well. But now I need to change that link using a `UIPickerView`.

In my `viewDidLoad` there is this code for loading feed items into `tableview`.

The first time it works good.

```
// Parse
feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:FEEDSFULLPAGE];

feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
feedParser.delegate = self;
feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
[feedParser parse];
```

With this code I call `UIPickerView` from a `UIBarButtonItem` on navigation bar:

```
- (void) showPicker:(id)sender {

self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false;
categorie.enabled = NO;

UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
rect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[rect setBackgroundColor:myColor];
[self.view addSubview:rect];

pickerviewToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 542, 320, 40)];
pickerviewToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
pickerviewToolbar.tintColor = nil;
[pickerviewToolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(AnnullaPickerView)] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(categoriaSelezionata:)] autorelease];

[pickerviewToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, flexSpace, doneButton,  nil]];

pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    // note this is default to NO

// Add the picker
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,585,0,0)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -400);
pickerView.transform = transform;
pickerviewToolbar.transform = transform;

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
[self.view addSubview:pickerviewToolbar];

[UIView commitAnimations];

[pickerView release];
[pickerviewToolbar release];
}
```

Now when one row of UIPIckerView is selected I do this:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

if ([[dataArray objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Ultime"]) {

    feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tarantocrasbasket.com/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=8&format=raw"];

    NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [dataArray objectAtIndex: row]);
    NSLog(@"Ultime: %@", feedURL);

} }
```

and finally when I click the done button of `UIPickerView`:

```
-(void) categoriaSelezionata:(id)sender {

self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true;
categorie.enabled = YES;
[rect removeFromSuperview];
[pickerView removeFromSuperview];
[pickerviewToolbar removeFromSuperview];
[self refresh]; }
```

I call the function "refresh" to parse new items from new link, but the app crashes!

If I put a NSLog to see if link is right, it crashes too.

The Xcode error is:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xf)

Why doesn't this work?